# python replacing values when the original value is unknown

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I'm looking to replace all values in a column, when that value is not empty/NaN. I can't seem to figure how to do the replace when I don't know the value of what I'm replacing.

I have this –

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', 'Q', '4'],
                    'B': ['5', '6', '7', '8']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['1', 'Q']})

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2,
               left_on=["A"],
               right_on=["C"],
               how='left')
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)

   A  B
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  Q  7
3  4  8

   C
0  1
1  Q

   A  B    C
0  1  5    1
1  2  6  NaN
2  Q  7    Q
3  4  8  NaN
```

In column Col C of df3 I want to replace all non-empty values with a 'Y'.

If I know the value replace works, but I won't know what these values are ahead of time.

```
df3['C'] = df3['C'].replace(['1'],'Y')
```

Desired output would look like this -

```
   A  B    C
0  1  5    Y
1  2  6  NaN
2  Q  7    Y
3  4  8  NaN
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line, it will work fine

```
df3.loc[df3['C'].notna(), 'C'] = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df3["C"].where(df3["C"].isna(),"Y",inplace=True)
```

read more : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html

Answer (score 0):

First get all rows with nan values.

```
# locate all non nan values in col C
nan = df3['C'].isna()
```

Then invert this locator and assign values in the column C

```
# invert to get the non nan rows
df3.loc[~nan, 'C'] = 'Y'
```

The result will be

```
   A  B    C
0  1  5    Y
1  2  6  NaN
2  Q  7    Y
3  4  8  NaN
```